# Django custom field - automatically add COLLATE to query

Tags: django, django-models, custom-fields

I'm trying to create a custom field which would automatically add COLLATE information into the WHERE part of SQL query:

```
class IgnoreDiacriticsField(models.TextField):

    def get_prep_lookup(self, lookup_type, value):
        if lookup_type == 'exact':
            return ' "' + self.get_prep_value(value) + '" COLLATE utf8_general_ci'
```

when I perform a query like this:

```
result = ModelClass.objects.filter(field='value')
```

then nothing is found, even though the query (print result.query) is valid and matches several rows. Am I doing something wrong?

The reason why I'm adding the collation iformation is that I want perform queries on those fields and ignore any diacritics.

Comment: Are you sure that field you trying to collate is not binary?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL 1.2.1p2 by any chance? From the Django documentation

> If you're using MySQLdb 1.2.1p2, Django's standard CharField class
>   will return unicode strings even with utf8_bin collation. However,
>   TextField fields will be returned as an array.array instance (from
>   Python's standard array module). There isn't a lot Django can do about
>   that, since, again, the information needed to make the necessary
>   conversions isn't available when the data is read in from the
>   database. This problem was fixed in MySQLdb 1.2.2, so if you want to
>   use TextField with utf8_bin collation, upgrading to version 1.2.2 and
>   then dealing with the bytestrings (which shouldn't be too difficult)
>   as described above is the recommended solution.